# show or hide a portlet based on the event of another portlet

Tags: java, liferay, portlet

I m new in Liferay portlet. Can any one tell me how I can show or hide a portlet based on the event of another portlet. I want coding in ice:spaces only not any other way. If someone know solution for this please reply me as soon as possible.
Note: I m using ice:spaces in xhtml not .jsp file.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using standard portlet technology this is not possible in a direct way. If using JSR 286 (Portlet 2.0) you could send an event (or a public render parameter) so that the portlet you want to hide can set its window state to minimized (you still see the title). Alternatively you could set the window state of the portlet requesting to hide others to maximized, this would hide all other portlets.

Comment: hi, thank for reply. can u send me some code, so, i can refer that.